# Modify raster layer display and symbology properties programmatically with arcpy or ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, raster, arcpy, symbology

I have over 1500 NITF files that I need to be able to modify the layer display and symbology of programmatically from within ArcMap. I need to set the properties outlined in red below:

[image]
[image]

I've looked through the arcpy docs and it doesn't look like these properties are exposed - honestly, I didn't expect them to be. I have a feeling I can get to them through ArcObjects. Anyone had any experience/luck modifying these properties programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe stretched raster symbology is rendered via [RasterStretchColorRampRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/001200000s83000000.htm), so interfaces implemented by this class are a good start. The renderer is assigned to your raster layer through [IRasterLayer.Renderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Renderer_Property/001200000pmv000000/).

1. Stretch type: [IRasterStretch.StretchType](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/StretchType_Property/001200000psr000000/)
2. High/low stretch values: [IRasterStretchMinMax](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRasterStretchMinMax_Interface/001200000ps3000000/)

Orthorectification is controlled by a different set of interfaces, pertaining to the raster data source itself. [IRaster2.GeodataXform](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GeodataXform_Property/001q0000022w000000/) can point to a geodata transformation class implementing [ISensorXform](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ISensorXform_Interface/001q000003q0000000/) which contains the orthorectification properties you see in the layer's property page.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to apply the same symbology to every image, you can setup one layer with the appropriate symbology, save it to a layer file, and then invoke the arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management to apply the symbology.

However, if you are really trying to deal with 1500 NITF files, you may consider using a Mosaic Dataset. You can apply an appropriate "stretch" to each NITF in the Mosaic Dataset and apply ortho rectification across all the images.

Comment: Nice James, that gets me about halfway there and changes the Symbology...but what about the Display properties...looking now to see if arcpy lets me get to those, and I will also investigate the Mosaic Dataset. Thanks!

Comment: The Mosaic Dataset is designed to apply ortho rectification (i.e. the display properties) en masse. At ArcGIS 10.1, you will be able to apply an ortho-on-the-fly raster function using a GP tool. I don't know of anything for 10.0 off the top of my head.