# Applying Stretch to Multiple Rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, symbology

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.0, how can I apply a stretch, which I would normally do by selecting 2 standard deviations in the "Symbology" tab of Layer Properties, to 200 rasters simultaneously?

Comment: These parameters cannot be accessed through arcpy, but can be changed using arcobjects. See this question for more information: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8771/modify-raster-layer-display-and-symbology-properties-programmatically-with-arcpy

Answer (score 2):

1. create a raster catalog in arccatalog
2. import your rasters in raster catalog
3. in arcmap go to properties of your raster catalog
4. symbology . you can select standard deviation for all of rasters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tool in arcgis:

**(1) Batch Calculate Statistics (Data Management)** 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m0000000

or the following in arcpy script:

**(2) Calculate Statistics (Data Management)** 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m3000000